Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers, $m$ odd, $n$ even, and $1+2+...+m$ and $1+2+...+n$ are perfect squares. Find $m+n$ for smallest $m$ and $n$.
My approach was purely of hit and trial method, since I could see that the question is solved with it with relative ease:
$1+2+3+...+(m-1)+m = k^2$   [Let]
Putting $m=1$
$1=1^2$
Also,
$1+2+3+...+(n-1)+n=l^2$ [Let]
Putting $n=8$
$36=6^2$
Hence $m+n=9$
Since this question was relatively simple and straightforward, it could be done with simple hit and trial. However, I want to learn an algebraic approach to it such that it could be applied to more complex questions as well.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping This could be useful to you with such exercise involving square and minimal quantity. (infinite descente e.g.)

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_triangular_number

@lhf I'm sorry, I am a little new to this stuff. Can you please explain the context in which square triangular numbers can be used here

I think the suggestion was that since 1+2+...+m is a triangular number combined with two consecutive triangular numbers summing to a square number you can conclude the result. I could be wrong but that is how I read it.

See this post.
